# Confusion related to creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conventions, klein-gordon-equation

I'm studying QFT from Peskin and from the book by Ashok Das, and there seems to be a disagreement between the creation and annihilation operators, for the scalar Klein Gordon field theory.

In Das, we have the following assertion :

If $\Phi(x,t)={\Phi(x,t)}^\dagger$, then $a^\dagger(-k)=a(k)$

However, in most other notes, this expression is missing, and we have something like :

$a(-k)a(k)=a(k)a(-k)$

These two seem to be contradicting each other. However, in both cases these are described to be the creation and annihilation operators.
If I combine the two above 'statements', I'd end up with $a^\dagger a=aa^\dagger$, which is clearly wrong.

Please tell me where I'm going wrong, as clearly I'm missing something obvious in here.

for example, If I follow the expression given in Das, and try to solve for the total momentum, I end up with the following,

$$P_i=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{p_i}{2}\left(a(p)^\dagger a(p) +a(p)a(p)^\dagger + a(p)^\dagger a(p) e^{2iEt} +a(p)a(p)^\dagger e^{-2iEt}   \right)$$

I'd get the correct answer from the first two terms, after normal ordering. However, the last two terms don't seem to go away. In the peskin method, I'd have got $a(-p),a(-p)^\dagger$ kind of terms, and then the last part would have vanished because of being an odd function in $p$. However, in the Das method, I've no idea how to make the last two terms go away.

Regards.